# Creating Video Controls

Tags: javascript, video, controls, jslint

```
window.onload = function () {

    "use strict";
    var video = document.getElementById("video"),
        playButton = document.getElementById("play-pause"),
        muteButton = document.getElementById("mute"),
        fullScreenButton = document.getElementById("full-screen"),
        seekBar = document.getElementById("seek-bar"),
        volumeBar = document.getElementById("volume-bar");

    muteButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
        if (video.muted === false) {

            video.muted = true;


            muteButton.innerHTML = "Unmute";
        } else {

            video.muted = false;


            muteButton.innerHTML = "Mute";
        }
    });

    fullScreenButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
        if (video.requestFullscreen) {
            video.requestFullscreen();
        } else if (video.mozRequestFullScreen) {
            video.mozRequestFullScreen(); // Firefox
        } else if (video.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
            video.webkitRequestFullscreen(); // Chrome and Safari
        }
    });

    seekBar.addEventListener("change", function () {

        var time = video.duration * (seekBar.value / 100);

        video.currentTime = time;
    });

    video.addEventListener("timeupdate", function () {

        var value = (100 / video.duration) * video.currentTime;

        seekBar.value = value;
    });

    seekBar.addEventListener("mousedown", function () {
        video.pause();
    });

    seekBar.addEventListener("mouseup", function () {
        video.play();
    });

    volumeBar.addEventListener("change", function () {
        video.volume = volumeBar.value;
    });
```

This is my code and I'm receiving 3 error codes from JSLint. 
1. Expected '(end)' at column 1, not column 7.
2. Expected '}' to match '{' from line 1 and instead saw '(end)'.
3. Expected ';' and instead saw '(end)'.

Any help getting this working would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your `window.onload` function seems to be unclosed, if that's the entire code. What does the console tell you

Answer (score 0):

```
/*jslint browser: true*/

window.onload = function () {

    "use strict";
    var video = document.getElementById("video"),
        //playButton = document.getElementById("play-pause"),
        muteButton = document.getElementById("mute"),
        fullScreenButton = document.getElementById("full-screen"),
        seekBar = document.getElementById("seek-bar"),
        volumeBar = document.getElementById("volume-bar");

    muteButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
        if (video.muted === false) {

            video.muted = true;


            muteButton.innerHTML = "Unmute";
        } else {

            video.muted = false;


            muteButton.innerHTML = "Mute";
        }
    });

    fullScreenButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
        if (video.requestFullscreen) {
            video.requestFullscreen();
        } else if (video.mozRequestFullScreen) {
            video.mozRequestFullScreen(); // Firefox
        } else if (video.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
            video.webkitRequestFullscreen(); // Chrome and Safari
        }
    });

    seekBar.addEventListener("change", function () {

        var time = video.duration * (seekBar.value / 100);

        video.currentTime = time;
    });

    video.addEventListener("timeupdate", function () {

        var value = (100 / video.duration) * video.currentTime;

        seekBar.value = value;
    });

    seekBar.addEventListener("mousedown", function () {
        video.pause();
    });

    seekBar.addEventListener("mouseup", function () {
        video.play();
    });

    volumeBar.addEventListener("change", function () {
        video.volume = volumeBar.value;
    });
};
```

This gives me no errors. `/*jslint browser: true*/` is to let jslint know `window`, `document` and so on are defined. I commented you unused `playButton`. And you forgot `;` at the end of your code.